# Java 3D: Where can I insert a "post rendering" FX?

Tags: 3d, effects, watermark, java-3d

I extended a Canvas3D and then I override the method "postSwap()", but my odd-even line effect is flickering a lot, what could be another good point for inserting this process?

```
public void postSwap() {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
    g2.addRenderingHints(map);
    g2.setColor(WipideaApplet.BCK2);
    int h = this.getHeight(), w = this.getWidth();
    for (int i=0;i<h;i++) {
        if (i%2==0)
            g2.drawLine(0, i, w, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution by myself which I post here to share it, if you have another one please post it :-)

```
@Override
public void postRender() {
    super.postRender();
    getGraphics2D().setColor(WipideaApplet.BCK2);
    int h = this.getHeight(), w = this.getWidth();
    for (int i=0;i<h;i++) {
            if (i%2==0) {
                getGraphics2D().drawLine(0, i, w, i);
            }
    }
    getGraphics2D().flush(true);
}
```

Pratically **getGraphics2D().flush(true);** is the most important, because avoid any flickering, at least on my centrino duo :-)