# Why java3d flickers when i call universe.getCanvas().getView().repaint();

Tags: java, java-3d

I was making a 3d modelling software that runs on java  (sorry for bad English )

I've added recently camera movement like that:

```
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                universe.getCanvas().getView().repaint();
                x-=0.001f;
                universe.getCanvas().getView().repaint();
                universe.getCanvas().getView().repaint();

            }
```

I read this page: [Why does the Java3D canvas flicker when I call Canvas3D.repaint()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29038302/why-does-the-java3d-canvas-flicker-when-i-call-canvas3d-repaint) and i tried to escape from flickering but it doesn't works.  How can I disable permanently flickering or make flickering invisible to eye or can I make a trick that copies old frame and pastes flickering time like that?

Comment: You should look at the source code of Sweet Home 3D on Sourceforge, its latest version uses Java3D 1.6.2 as far as I remember. Java3D 1.7 is available. I don't know which version you use.

Comment: I found an hopefull answer from this old post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789063/java-3d-where-can-i-insert-a-post-rendering-fx. universe.getCanvas().getGraphics2D().flush(true) after repaint